# Solve $2x^{98}+5x^{97}+5x^{96}+...5x+3=0$

Tags: polynomials

> Find real solutions for $x$, in$ \,\,\,f(x)=2x^{98}+5x^{97}+5x^{96}+...5x+3=0$, It is also given that $x+1$ is a factor

Since $x+1$ is a factor, we can write $f(x) =(x+1)(2x^{97}+3x^{96}+2x^{95}...+3)$

can someone give a hint what to do next? Thanks.

Comment: What does dots mean? Are there unknown coefficents or are all 5?

Comment: All coefficients are 5 in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(x)=5x(x^{97}+x^{96}+...+x+1)+3-3x^{98}=5x \frac{1-x^{98}}{1-x}+3(1-x^{98})$  for $x \ne 1$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And if I complete it like this, is it ok?
$\frac{(1-x^{98})(2x+3)}{(1-x)}=0$ So $x=\frac{-3}{2}$ or $x=-1$ ( here we are neglecting x=1 answer since it doesn't satisfy f(x)

Comment: Yes, we have $f(x)=0 \iff x \in \{-\frac{3}{2}, -1\}$